# the body message of email has %20 between every space

Tags: javascript, email

The link to the ide I code in from sololearn.com is https://code.sololearn.com/Wg70wiK3e0h3/#html but there I can never actually send the email, so then I use the notepad and the body message that is sent is filled by %20 as if it was a link. The "code" below is the function in which I build the body message and send the email. If you go to my full code in sololearn it is in line 2000ish and its called in line 3000ish. Btw the rest of the code is working perfectly fine.

This function has more to it but it's too big to put it here but basically I add the data to the message variable, just like the gender one but multiple times with multiple variables, but all with the same syntax

```
     function sendEmail(){

            message = "Hi this is just a way for you to have all the main data summed up saved in your email inbox. \n \n";

            message += "Gender: ";

            message += genderreturn;

            message += " \n";

            url = "mailto:" + emailaddrreturn + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;

            location.href = url; //(might want to use window.location or something else here)
}
```

Comment: because %20 is encoded space, that is how they work in urls

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: Any idea on what to do to solve this?

Comment: Solved what? You have described a behavior, but at least for me it's impossible to parse out an actual problem or something you want solved. But it does sound like you want to have a look at `encodeURIComponent("Hi this is"); // returns "Hi%20this%20is"` and `decodeURIComponent("Hi%20this%20is"); // returns "Hi this is"`.

Comment: I mean, already tried those, but then maybe because it's a type of "link" it has to be encoded, so when I decode it it does not go to Gmail cause there is no such thing as a decoded link. So like, I'm asking if maybe there is some other way to send the email, so the body message doesn't get all screwed up. I think this can possibly be the only way.